# Weird sweep of dark and bright border on a material

Tags: animation, materials

[Video](https://youtu.be/9PaSlUYR3oY)

So I made a render and made a short camera pan animation on it. The brick wall at the back shows this weird line sweep from right to left but when I check on the render as a static image the line isn't there.  How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are not getting answers, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I guess there will be a process of elimination. 1. The animation is rendered as an image sequence, without the possibility of compression artefacts?